# Which AmqpEvent or AmqpException to handle when an exclusive consumer fails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have two instances of the same application, running in different virtual machines. I want to grant exclusive access to a queue for the consumer of one of them, while invalidating the local cache that is used by the consumer on the other.

Now, I have figured out that I need to handle [`ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#consumer-events) but I am guessing that implementing an `ApplicationListener` for this event is not going to ensure that I am receiving this event because of an exclusive consumer exception. I might want to check the `Throwable` of the event, or event further checks.

Which subclass of `AmqpException` or what further checks should I perform to ensure that the exception is received due to exclusive consumer access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in the listener container implementations is like this:

```
if (e.getCause() instanceof ShutdownSignalException
            && e.getCause().getMessage().contains("in exclusive use")) {
        getExclusiveConsumerExceptionLogger().log(logger,
                "Exclusive consumer failure", e.getCause());
        publishConsumerFailedEvent("Consumer raised exception, attempting restart", false, e);
    }
```

So, we indeed raise a `ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent` event and you can trace the cause message like we do in the framework, but on the other hand you can just inject your own `ConditionalExceptionLogger`:

```
/**
 * Set a {@link ConditionalExceptionLogger} for logging exclusive consumer failures. The
 * default is to log such failures at WARN level.
 * @param exclusiveConsumerExceptionLogger the conditional exception logger.
 * @since 1.5
 */
public void setExclusiveConsumerExceptionLogger(ConditionalExceptionLogger exclusiveConsumerExceptionLogger) {
```

and catch such an exclusive situation over there.

Also you can consider to use `RabbitUtils.isExclusiveUseChannelClose(cause)` in your code:

```
/**
 * Return true if the {@link ShutdownSignalException} reason is AMQP.Channel.Close
 * and the operation that failed was basicConsumer and the failure text contains
 * "exclusive".
 * @param sig the exception.
 * @return true if the declaration failed because of an exclusive queue.
 */
public static boolean isExclusiveUseChannelClose(ShutdownSignalException sig) {
```

Comment: Highly appreciated. I was aware that I could use a `ConditionalExceptionLogger`, but the method I picked seemed a bit more lexically correct. How do I get `ShutdownSignalException` from the `ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent`. Would casting its `Throwable` into it after an `instanceof` check work?

Comment: That's correct, but it has to be a `cause`. See `if(e.getCause() instanceof ShutdownSignalException` mentioned above.

Comment: @ArtemBilan thanks for an explanation. I'm interested in the logger override approach you described. Is there any customizer/configurer adapter I can use to inject this logger? A simple declaration of `@Bean` doesn't work here and as I understand this bean is not available in the context so I wonder how can I customize it. I'm using spring-cloud-steam with rabbit binder

Comment: The Rabbit Binder uses a `MessageListenerContainer` from Spring AMQP. And its `AbstractMessageListenerContainer` has a `setExclusiveConsumerExceptionLogger()`. The binder, on its own, has a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` you can use to inject your custom logger: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_advanced_listener_container_configuration